# Run a list of bash scripts consecutively

Tags: bash, cron

I have a load of bash scripts that backup different directories to different locations. I want each one to run every day. However, I want to make they don't run simultaneously.

I've wrote a script that basically just calls each script in succession and sits in cron.daily, but I want a way for this script to work even if I add and remove backup scripts without having to manually edit it.

So what I need to go is generate a list of the scripts (e.g. "dir -1 /usr/bin/backup*.sh") and then run each script it finds in turn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/sh    
for script in /usr/bin/backup*.sh
do
$script
done
```

Comment: This is not scalable, since the glob will fail if it expands to too many files.

Comment: And it will fail if there are no files.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
for SCRIPT in /usr/bin/backup*.sh
do
   [ -x "$SCRIPT" ] && [ -f "$SCRIPT" ] && $SCRIPT   
done
```

Comment: That `x` bit is a very nice idea, as makes it very easy to temporarily disable one of those backup scripts just by running `chmod -x backup-foo.sh`.

Comment: @ghostdog: If you are going to call `/bin/bash`, you really aught to use [[ instead of [

Comment: @Siegex, thanks point taken. I will use it where its due, but in this case, using [ is perfectly fine.

Comment: I know this is very, very old, but I just stumbled upon this answer. What's the [ -f ] test for? -x already tests if a file exists?

Answer (score 2):

If your system has [`run-parts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man8/run-parts.8.html) then that will take care of it for you. You can name your scripts like "10script", "20anotherscript" and they will be run in order in a manner similar to the `rc*.d` hierarchy (which is run via init or Upstart, however). On some systems it's a script. On mine it's a binary executable.

It is likely that your system is using it to run hourly, daily, etc., cron jobs just by dropping scripts into directories such as /etc/cron.hourly/

Pay particular attention, though, to [how you name your scripts](http://gnuru.org/article/952/cron-run-parts-script-names). (Don't use dots, for example.) Check the man page specific to your system, since file naming restrictions may vary.